# Map of maps with fixed range of keys

Tags: c++, dictionary, data-structures

I'm using a map-of-maps data structure like:

```
template <typename Key1, typename Key2, typename T>
using MapOfMaps = std::unordered_map<Key1, std::unordered_map<Key2, T>>;
```

My issue is the range of values of `Key2` for each `Key1` is guaranteed to be the same, and if `Key2` is a large object, it can get very expensive to keep replicating the range of keys.

So this is essentially a matrix-like map, where the number of 'columns' is fixed, but the number of rows may grow. Required properties of the container would be:

- Amortised constant time access.
- Iteration over all keys (e.g. `std::tuple<Key1, Key2, T>`).
- Iteration over `Key2` for a specific `Key1` (e.g. `std::pair<Key2, T>`).
- Storage of only one copy of the range of `Key2` objects.

As a somewhat far-fetched, but illustrative, example of such a structure, consider:

```
using ExamResultMap = MapOfMaps<Student, Exam, Result>;
```

where each student must take the same set of exams.

Is there any existing container that already implements such behaviour? If not, how might be the best way to go about implementing such a container? My first idea was something like:

```
template <typename Key1, typename Key2, typename T>
class MatrixMap
{
    std::vector<Key2> key2s_;
    std::unordered_map<Key1, std::vector<T>> values_;
    std::unordered_map<std::reference_wrapper<const Key2>, std::size_t> key2_indicies_;
public:
    // API
};
```

Is this a good way to implement this?